# Is it OK to all values in a column of a table without limit?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the product ids of the product used by a customer with the query,

```
select
   v.product_id
from
  TableA as v
join
  TableB as f
on
  v.id = f.id
where
    f.product_name = "<some_name>"
  and
    f.customer_id = "<id>"
```

**Note** : product_id is the primary key of TableA

There could be too many rows matching the criteria and in the worst case it could be the entire value of a column in a table.

Is this OK to execute the query without any limit operator? How could I get to know the query which I run is safe (ie; produces no OOM kind of issues) when the result set obtained is too large?

**EDIT**

This is my `getMySQLConnection` part of my code

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname; 
String clazz = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"; 
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName(clazz).newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
```

Some thing like a `GET` request which could be able to transfer around 2-8kb (as far as I remember). what is the maximum size of data (ie' the result set data) that could be transferred with this url connection?

Comment: MySQL can output a large result set pretty fast but you need to worry about indexes because you are joining you might also want to add the index  `TableB(id, product_name, customer_id)` or create a histogram if you are using MySQL 8+ you better optimizer statistics..

Comment: I'm getting this result set in my application layer. So, will this cause any oom kinda issues when the size of values returned are too high?

Comment: Your application needs ofcource reserve RAM memory to handle the result set.

Comment: So, how could i calculate (or) estimate the size of the result set? So that i could guess what my safe limit is. Here the product_id is a varchar column of max length 80

Comment: That's really cool @RaymondNijland. Thank you :-)

Comment: I've added the sample snippet of how I'm making connection to my mysql. would like to know the maximum amount of data that could be transferred via this url call.

Comment: "what is the maximum size of data (ie' the result set data) that could be transferred with this url connection?" as big as your memory runs out in thoery..

Comment: Ok @RaymondNijland. I was not sure whether there would be some limit something like one we have for `GET` and `POST` http requests. So I was asking...

Comment: And why we are doing `SELECT (80 + 1) ` instead of `SELECT (80) + <the_other_query>` ?

Comment: Actually better would be `SELECT (80 + 2)`   Because VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes..

Comment: When I'm executing this query - I'm getting something like `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from ...`  Am I missing  something?

Comment: i think i need coffee that previous query i've given looks just plain wrong so i've removed the comment with the query ... `SELECT 
 ((80 + 2) + records.record_count) AS bytes
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS record_count
  FROM
   TableB
  WHERE
   product_name = "<some_name>" AND customer_id = "<id>"
  
) AS records`  should do the trick

Comment: I just calculated manually @RaymondNijland. If the total amount of tuples returned is 15L and if the size of them is 82 then I going to consume around 418MB data in my RAM which is very minimal. So, I need not worry on limit i guess...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170949/discussion-between-natasha-and-raymond-nijland).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use limit in the query. otherwise, you will not get the whole product list.
and the worst case happens only if there is only one customer on your site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the purpose of the query is.

Do you need to evaluate EVERY row which meets that query criteria? Is so then you would need to SELECT without limit.

However if you do not need every row as in a paginated report, you could use LIMIT MAX MIN.

Comment: I need all the columns which matches my criteria.

Comment: Then you need to leave out limit @Natasha

Comment: But what happens when the number of tuples returned are more than 10 lakh (something like a large number). How could I guess my safer side limit?

Comment: Agreed with @RaymondNijland. If you are finding that the query is inefficient in some way then you will likely need to look at indexing the field in your WHERE clause, or some other way to optimize the data.

Comment: @Natasha just spitballing here:  if the user is triggering this query on demand maybe you could offer THEM the option to limit the query in a GUI, or run it in the background and send them the response at a later point in time via email.

Comment: @dg : I'm just trying to collect this data (as a one time process) or may be when it is required.